# How to limit post (Exception pages) for current user in each role in front end?

Tags: posts, users, front-end, limit

**Thank you for reading this question**

I need an option or code for each user in each role to see only their posts at the **front end**, and other users' posts to be completely hidden from them, even in search results (without any messages or effects).

**More details:**

The user has to log in to receive the content, and when they log in, they only sees their posts (as if there are no other posts on the website).

I need all pages to be excluded (show for all). Only hide other users' posts

Any help would be appreciated

[image: Home Page screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried? What *specific* problem are you having? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/402789/edit) to include any relevant code.

Comment: I want every user to see only their posts when logged in.
Visible items for all users:
1- Pages
2- Category
3- Tags
Or anything in common between user posts.

Unsigned users do not see any content, not even pages

Comment: You would just run a check on each post in the `while` loop to check if the current users ID matches the author ID of the post.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.